# Using aurelia-cli unable to get bootstrap and a couple of templates to work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

We're researching aurelia-cli as a replacement for webpack and trying to understand its bundling and packaging by running a simple app with bootstrap and a couple of templates.

what we did:

1. au new with standard configuration and install dependencies
2. added `import 'bootstrap';` to main.js after the environment import statement
3. npm installed jquery and bootstrap
4. added entries to aurelia.json

   ```
        "jquery",
         {
           "name": "bootstrap",
           "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
           "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
           "deps": ["jquery"],
           "exports": "$",
           "resources": [
             "css/bootstrap.css"
           ]
         }
   ```
5. Added bootstrap to app

```js
export class App {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="pull-left" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Events <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Discussion</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Job Board</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <compose view-model="events"></compose>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <compose view-model="sponsors"></compose>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

6. Added sponsors.html & sponsors.js and events.html & events.js in src at same level as app.js. both html and js files for these two contain just  and class definitions respectively. They're empty otherwise.

When I run au run --watch, I get 3 js errors and 2 warnings:

```
vendor-bundle.js:24678 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ vendor-bundle.js:24678
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
```

> above error appears twice

```
vendor-bundle.js:3777 Uncaught TypeError: h.load is not a function
```

Warnings:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Failed loading required CSS file: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
    at fixupCSSUrls (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23479:13)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23518:16
From previous event:
    at CSSResource.load (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23517:10)
    at ResourceDescription.load (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19128:28)
    at ResourceModule.load (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19077:37)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19438:43
From previous event:
    at ViewEngine.importViewResources (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19407:52)
    at ViewEngine.loadTemplateResources (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19377:19)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19325:41
From previous event:
    at ViewEngine.loadViewFactory (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19309:67)
    at ConventionalViewStrategy.loadViewFactory (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:16729:25)
    at HtmlBehaviorResource.load (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20067:29)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20600:18
From previous event:
    at CompositionEngine.createController (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20588:71)
    at CompositionEngine._createControllerAndSwap (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20567:19)
    at CompositionEngine.compose (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20647:21)
    at TemplatingEngine.compose (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20915:38)
    at Aurelia.setRoot (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10267:21)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:82:22
From previous event:
    at Object.configure (http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:81:21)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10022:22
From previous event:
    at config (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10017:48)
    at handleApp (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10008:12)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10041:13
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10039:40
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10038:29
From previous event:
    at run (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10034:26)
    at Object. (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10061:3)
    at Object.execCb (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3785:299)
    at Object.check (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3774:50)
    at Object.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3779:58)
    at Object.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3783:433)
    at Object. (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3778:436)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3763:140
    at y (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3762:207)
    at Object.enable (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3777:469)
    at Object.init (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3772:154)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3782:308
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues you are seeing with Bootstrap are because Bootstrap's JavaScript is not written to expect using a module aware jQuery. It expects jQuery to be a property on the `window` object. It can be seen in line 7 here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L7

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery')
}
```

Currently, the Aurelia CLI is unable to load font files, and thus doesn't really support bundling Bootstrap's CSS. My personal recommendation is to load Bootstrap (both CSS and JS) from a CDN. It is necessary to also load jQuery from a CDN in this case.

Also, please do not use `compose` to do what you're doing here. `events` and `sponsors` should be custom elements that are loaded using the `require` element. Using `compose` to load them is a misuse of the `compose` element, and you will pay a performance penalty for using it.

Comment: I was following brian noyes aurelia course but using aurelia-cli for build. I read the official documentation that gave me an idea that the syntax might be wrong. The learning though is that to be careful/mindful with/of versioning on the tutorial, training material, tools and IDEs and their plugins/extensions. Phew!

Answer (score -1):

We managed to fix this.

There was no problem with the bootstrap or jquery plugin even though they popped up.

After going through Aurelia documentation for  element, we saw that it should be constructed like so:

```
<compose view-model="events" view.bind="events.html"></compose>
```

rather than

```
<compose view-model="events"></compose>
```

we use Aurelia Snippets 1.0.4 extension within Visual Studio Code which gave us this syntax when creating a compose element:

```
<compose view="url" view-model="modelname"></compose>
```

This obviously is not updated with the framework update! The error messages weren't very obvious either.

EDIT:
Please see comments from a member of the aurelia core team for when to use `<compose>`. Also be mindful of the tutorial or training video. Always check the official documentation [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/persona/developer)

Comment: Please DO NOT USE COMPOSE THIS WAY!!!!! I keep seeing this everywhere on Stack Overflow. The `compose` element is for DYNAMIC composition. What you are doing here is static composition. You've created a custom element, and Aurelia will wire that up for you. SO USE IT! `<events></events>`

Comment: Let me reiterate here. Using `compose` instead of a custom element when you are not doing anything dynamic WILL SLOW DOWN YOUR APP. Don't use `compose` unless you are doing something dynamic. This is coming direct from the Aurelia Core Team.